# How to write a 'hotcorners' script in Python?

Tags: application-development, python, scripts

I'm using Lubuntu 13.04, and a feature that I miss from Compiz is the hot-corners: it simply runs some command when the mouse cursor reaches a corner of the screen.

So, I was thinking about writing a script to handle that for me. But some questions arose:

- How do i get the current mouse position? I looked for this, found some enviroment variables, but none of them is about the cursor position.
- I've seen many bash scripts, but could I write one in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [python-xlib [image: Install python-xlib]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-xlib) module will allow you to get the current mouse position. Here's a quick example:

```
>>> from Xlib import display
>>> d = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
>>> print d["root_x"], d["root_y"]
```

Though, you're in luck. There is already a python script that does exactly what you want from the Crunchbang Linux distro. Take a look at the `cb-hotcorners` script in the [CrunchBang window manager hacks GitHub repo](https://github.com/corenominal/cb-wmhacks).

Comment: oh yes, that's exactly what i want! cd-hotcorners is nice too, but i want to try making my own, mainly for learning.
thanks for your answer (and for fixing my first post)! :)